# How to Accessibility api upload to play store

Tags: java, android

[image]

How to modify the above request for upload application in play store which uses accessibility APIs?
This application is auto click on screen.

Comment: From what I know Google restricts usage of the accessibility API. Only apps that use the accessibility API in the way Google had designed it are now allowed: help disabled people. In my understanding automation of button clicks will be rejected, unless you can explain how that helps disabled people.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.